# Why won't my EliteBook 8460p let me boot from a Windows 10 Install USB but it will let me boot from the same USB with a linux distro?

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, hp-elitebook

I have an HP EliteBook 8460p. I am trying to install Windows 10 on it. It will not let me do this and the only clue I have is this error that flashes for a split second.

[image: Error]

Sorry for the bad quality but I was only able to read it by capturing it with my slow motion function on my phone and stepping through the frames to see it.

Anyway I've tried different USB's. I event put a linux distro on the USB to see if it would boot from there and it did. However it just only seems to do it with Windows 10. I've tried an older ISO of Windows 10 too for good measure too.

Why am I unable to boot from the USB only when I'm trying to load the Windows 10 installer?

Comment: Does this have BIOS or UEFI?  Why do you have `Intel AMT` enabled by the way? This a personal or company machine?

Comment: It has BIOS. There is a legacy option int he BIOS to boot with UEFI but I tried that too however it made no difference.

Comment: As for why Intel AMT is enabled? I don't know why it is enabled. Never heard of it until I saw this message. It's a personal machine.

Comment: AMT isn't configured.  So it should be disabled.  Be sure you boot with Legacy mode disabled.  Does the storage device have any partitions currently?  If it does then, are we dealing with MBR or GPT, edit your question to include all this vital information